# how to find out when a link was first tweeted

Tags: twitter

http://isitold.com/ somehow determines when a link/url was first tweeted. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the twitter api, does anybody know?

I'd like to use when a link was first tweeted in a time decay function in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like twitter does not provide historical tweets (search api will not work).

You can get access to historical tweet information with a service like Topsy http://www.topsy.com http://code.google.com/p/otterapi/ (api on topsy).

Answer (score 0):

You can search tweets with this link using the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) to retrieve the oldest tweet possible.

Comment: I saw that, but couldn't see an option to get the oldest. I see a since_id option, and a most recent option. What would the query be to get, for example, the first tweet for google.com?

Comment: All the tweets have got a numerical ID which depends if the tweet is old or not. Oldest tweets have got a lower ID and the most recent tweets have got a higher ID. In the queries, you got `rpp * page` tweets that are included between since_id and max_id : `since_id < the tweets <= max_id`. With these details, you should know how to do to retrieve the oldest tweets by yourself `;-)`. For your query, you just have to search the URL (`q=google.com` in your example), what else ?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I still don't understand. Are you suggesting I plug in random max_id numbers until I find the oldest tweet? The tweets are always returned by most recent, so how would I find the oldest?

Comment: Probably missing something, but how do you come up with the since_id and max_id without guessing?

Comment: Ok after a bit more research, it's impossible to get the time a link was first tweeted because the search api only goes back like 10 days... I ended up using Topsy, a historical tweet service.

Answer (score 0):

I have written [Who Tweeted It First](http://ctrlq.org/first/) using YQL and JS to find the oldest tweet for any topic. It is essentially scraping data from the Twitter search page as the official API doesn't return the previous tweets.